# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \sec^3x \sin x \,dx $

Tags: calculus

Was working on some trig-based integration. I've been confident with easier ones, but can't seem to approach this one correctly.

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sec^3x \sin x \,dx $

Which method of integration should I use to solve this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 sec^3(x)sin(x)dx = \int_0^1tan(x)sec^2(x)
$$

setting $u = tan(x)$

$du = sec^2(x)dx$

$dx = cos^2(x) du \therefore$

$$
\int_{tan(0)}^{tan(1)} u du
$$

$$
= \frac{tan^2(1)}{2}-\frac{tan^2(0)}{2}
$$

$$= \frac{tan^2(1)}{2}$$

Comment: Pointer: use `\tan x` to get $\tan x$ and not `tan x`, which gets you $tan x$. Ditto for $\sin, \cos, \cdots$. Simply put, begin each trig function with a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

You can use u substitution, noting that $sec (x)= {1 \over cos (x)}$ and the derivative of the cosine is the negative sine

Comment: Using the u-sub I get an answer of $(-sec^2x)/2 $

Comment: You added an unnecessary negative, because the derivative is NEGATIVE sine.

Comment: I understand Eric Lawson's answer below, but am confused as his method yields a tangent instead of a secant.

Comment: @user195747 Notice that 

$$
\sec^2(1)/2 - \sec^2(0)/2 = \tan^2(1)/2
$$

Comment: YOu're right, that answer also works. I'm trying to figure out why both work.

Comment: But the same answer works for an indefinite integral also.

Comment: @PhzksStdnt

$$
\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{2\cos^2(1)} - \frac{1}{2\cos^2(0)} = \frac{\cos^2(0)-cos^2(1)}{cos^2(0)cos^2(1)}]
$$

Since \cos^2(0) = 1

$$
\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1-\cos^2(1)}{cos^2(1)}] = \frac{1}{2} \frac{sin^2(1)}{cos^2(1)} = \frac{\tan^2(1)}{2}
$$

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, because the secant squared plus one equals the tangent. So it is the same as adding an arbitrary constant.